# How to count max value in one month from 2 table

Tags: mysql, datetime, count, rdbms

I have 2 table on my transaction

Table One

```
id |    date       |   cust_id               |     driver_number
1     2019-01-02          1                         F 3350 NN
2     2019-04-02          2                         AX 111 Z
3     2019-05-02          3                         S 787  X
4     2019-05-02          4                         T 9090 M
5     2019-06-02          3                         P 8989 L
```

Table Two

```
driver_number |    price       
F 3350 NN        350000
AX 111 Z         400000
S 787  X         375000
T 9090 M         900000
P 8989 L         500000
```

How do I count total transaction from two tables above in one month as per requested .
In example, request for total transaction in May so the result is like below

```
period         |    total       
May                1275000
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you try writing a query with a simple JOIN in it?

Comment: What is table 2 about?

Comment: **Pro tip:** Beginners are welcome, but we expect some effort on your behalf to be expended on attempting to solve your own problem prior to a question being asked. 
We dont write code for you although we are very willing to help you fix issues with code you have written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `MONTH(T1.date) = 5` and `SUM(price)` the expected result is achievable

```
SELECT MONTH(T1.date) AS Period, SUM(price) AS `Total`
FROM TableOne T1
JOIN TableTwo T2 ON T2.driver_number = T1.driver_number
WHERE MONTH(T1.date) = 5
GROUP BY MONTH(T1.date)
```